# Tabhost with single or separate activity, when to use?

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I'm a android beginner, just begin with tabhost from a example at developer.android.com. In that example, they use 2 activities for 2 tabs and i just do like that in my app.

My app has 2 tabs, 1 main tab and 1 tab used for settings, it means value on tab2 usually used by tab1 but i realize that when switch from tab2 to tab1, every value on tab2 was reset. How can't i get values at tab2 from tab1 and how to keep values when switch tab? Use just one activity? And please show me when to use 1 activity, when to use many activities for many tabs.

Thanks you.
ps: i think when works on tabs are independent, we should use many activities, otherwise use just 1 activity :-?

Answer (score 0):

With respect to your second (settings) tab: you may want to read about Android's [persistent data storage options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref). You could create your own layout for the settings activity, store the user input into the app's shared settings and load them when returning to the first tab, or switching back the settings tab.

Alternatively, you can also take a look at the [PreferenceActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html), or preferably the Fragment variant of that, if you're considering modern production code.

The question how many activities to use is quite ambiguous as it really depends on the type of app you're writing and the data/user/design flow in it. I would say that combining unrelated functionality into a single activity is not the way to go. You can savely use a seperate tab for settings, although I would consider making it a menu item if users of your app do not require to access the settings on a regular basis. That way it won't take up any space in the main UI.